# Can't get local file test.txt using http://localhost:8080/test.txt

Tags: node.js, express, server, localhost

I've got a server running on `localhost:8080`, and my files are arranged like this:

```
/test
    server.js
    chatroom.html
    test.txt
```

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/chatroom.html");
});
app.listen(8080);
```

So in my browser when I go to `http://localhost:8080` I get served `chatroom.html` just fine.

**The problem I'm having:**

But when I go to `http://localhost:8080/chatroom.html` it shows me "Cannot GET /chatroom.html"

And, likewise, if I go to `http://localhost:8080/test.txt` it shows me "Cannot GET /chatroom.html"

I don't understand what's going wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only defined one path for Express, the root path "/". If you want other files available you need to call app.get() for them as well.

Or, you can put those static assets in a directory and [use express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve them.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me if I'm understanding this? I had been thinking, apparently incorrectly, that entering `http://localhost:8080/test.txt` into the browser would be similar to entering in `file:/// . . . /test/test.txt`, except it would just be a path relative to `localhost:8080`. Are you saying that actually, entering `http://localhost:8080/test.txt` sends a GET request to the server, which it doesn't know how to process?

Comment: Right. When you're using a web server like Apache or Nginx, they're usually configured to serve static files if they exist and only reach out to a backend like PHP or node.js if the requested path doesn't match a file. But by connecting to port 8080, you're taking to node & Express directly, and Express only knows about the paths you tell it about and whatever middleware you register.